# Google App Engine - Task Queue taking too long to start random tasks

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Our clients are having problems with our appengine python application that requires task queues processing to generate reports and display as soon as they are finished. That workaround to the well known GAE slowness and timeouts have been working well for us until recently.

Last week we started getting complains at how long the users had to wait for the reports. It used to be at most a minute, but now it can take more than 10 minutes.

Furthermore, I can't reproduce the problem, but looking at the task queue, I can see that those tasks are simply not getting started.

Bellow is a screenshot of one of the queues (not the one that generate the reports, but the problem is happening in all queues).

http://www.clipular.com/c/4829223501430784.png?k=QaP2kedZm6NcvrKzwVSJqq2YI1g

We can see that there are no tasks running, but the only task in the queue did not start until it completed 7 minutes of waiting. And look at the ETA, it's predicting that task should start in the past. Eventually it went off, but why didn't it start sooner?

Reasons that I already ruled out:

- Not enough resources or instances: it happens even after midnight, when we get just a few requests.
- Bad queue configuration: Not that, we have all variety of queue configurations and it happens in then all. For example, Maximum Rate=350/s, Bucket Size=400, Maximum Concurrent=400.

Comment: I'm having similar issues but my tasks generally take less than a minute to execute.  Still annoying though.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem stopped happening without any action. Apparently, it's due to some kind of failure in the GAE servers. The problem lasted for about two weeks.

One action that can minimize the problem, however, is to spread your tasks in separate queues, if possible.

--- edit ---

It's happening again. The only thing we could do to solve the problem was to write a script that keeps asking to run the late tasks if they are found. It runs on https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues via tampermonkey.